# Which Cassandra node should I connect to?

Tags: cassandra, netflix

I might be misunderstanding something here, as it's not clear to me how I should connect to a Cassandra cluster. I have a Cassandra 1.2.1 cluster of 5 nodes managed by Priam, on AWS. i would like to use Astyanax to connect to this cluster by using a code similar to the code bellow:

```
conPool = new ConnectionPoolConfigurationImpl(getConecPoolName())               .setMaxConnsPerHost(CONNECTION_POOL_SIZE_PER_HOST).setSeeds(MY_IP_SEEDS)
                .setMaxOperationsPerConnection(100) // 10000
```

What should I use as MY_IP_SEEDS? Should I use the IPs of all my nodes split by comma? Or should I use the IP of just 1 machine (the seed machine)? If I use the ip of just one machine, I am worried about overloading this machine with too many requests.

I know Priam has the "get_seeds" REST api (https://github.com/Netflix/Priam/wiki/REST-API) that for each node returns a list of IPs and I also know there is one seed per RAC. However, I am not sure what would happen if the seed node gets down... I would need to connect to others when trying to make new connections, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seed nodes are only for finding the way into the cluster on node startup - no overload problems.

Of course one of the nodes must be reachable and up in the cluster to get the new one up and running.

So the best way is to update the seed list from Priam before starting the node. Priam should be behind an automatically updated DNS entry.

If you're highest availability you should regularly store the current list of seeds from Priam  and store them in a mirrored fashion just as you store your puppet or chef config to be able to get nodes up even when Priam isn't reachable.